# Git not using user from Global Configuration file

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on AWS EC2, git version 2.34.1

Below is my `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
        helper =
        helper = !/usr/bin/gh auth git-credential
[credential "https://gist.github.com"]
        helper =
        helper = !/usr/bin/gh auth git-credential
[safe]
        directory = /var/www/html/wix
        directory = /var/www/html/wix-native-app
[user]
        name = JXX XXXha
        email = jXXXX0@gmail.com
        signingkey = 8XXXXXXXXXXX1
[commit]
        gpgsign = true
```

However when I try to commit, I get below error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-46-106:/var/www/html/wix-native-app$ sudo git commit
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: no email was given and auto-detection is disabled
```

But as seen in my `.gitconfig` file, username and email are already set. Is there anything else to be done in configuration for commit to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing git with `sudo` i.e. as user `root`. So git will look for the config in `/root/.gitconfig`, while you set the config in `~/.gitconfig` i.e. in the home path of your non-privileged user.

You have two options:

1. Change permissions and/or ownership of `/var/www/html/wix-native-app` so that your unpriviledged user `ubuntu` has permissions to read and write this path. Make sure to include `-R` to your `chmod`/`chgrp`commands to apply the changes to all files and subfolders.

   Pros:

   - You do not need a privileged user to change the content of your web server. Users with the right to change the content will not get the rights to tamper with the server config.
   - You can use groups to assign permissions to multiple users.
   - If you have different users responsible for different sub-folders of `/var/www/html/`, you can assign them write permissions to only the folders they are in charge of.
2. Copy your `~/.gitconfig` to `/root/.gitconfig` so git will find the config if you run it sudo'ed.

   Con:

   - In most cases, you should not consider changing the web servers content as an administrative task which requires privileged account.